# Dynamic UITextview inside a UIView, which inturn is inside a UIScrollview, all views enabled with auto layout malfunctions if long text loaded

Tags: ios, dynamic, autolayout, constraints, uitextview

I have a dynamic `UITextView` within a `UIView` which in-turn is placed within a `UIScrollView` as in

[image]

Now, I tried so many options to make the views adjust if a long text comes, but constraint error appears in my every trials, what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: why a text view not a label?

Comment: Literally it might get large amount of text!

Comment: should still be a label or the text view should scroll the text

Comment: I need the view, present above the textview also to move up while scrolling, so cannot use textview scroll. Do you mean that I should try a label?

Comment: even if I use a label, how will the parent UIView's height increase according to the label's text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that `UITextView` doesn't have an intrinsic size and that's what you need. You should use `UILabel` instead because it does have an intrinsic size.

So, using a label and ensuring the your constraints pin all the views edges together you can have the container view automatically resized (so the content of the scroll view is automatically resized) for you.

Comment: great solution, had to reassign every constraints, but worth the pain, label expands without affecting the outer views. Thanks!